# What would cause a Klein ET300 to Identify multiple breakers for the same outlet?

Tags: electrical-panel

Environment : There are 2, 200 amp residential services coming into the house. Each has it's own breaker box. The home has had extensive remodeling over the years. I have found 2 different outlets that when the transmitter is plugged in, the receiver after multiple passes over both breaker boxes identifies multiple breakers.  In one case, the breaker that actually kills the power to the outlet being tested is in one breaker box but the ET300 also consistently identifies two separate breakers in the other breaker box.  The outlet is located in a kitchen island with other outlets, garbage disposal, two dishwashers, .... etc that all appear to each be on different breakers spread across both of the two main panels.  He ideas as to how I should proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I have had trouble with the automatic modules like this in the same panel even with repeated checks as needed by the unit to identify the correct breaker the signal must be the same value on both breakers. The only way to be 100% sure is with very expensive meters +500$ like the greenlee CS8000. There is a trick I learned before getting an expensive scanner, installing an old fashion light flasher in a fixture (the small blue button that went under the lamp) and then look with an amp clamp for the circuit that was pulsing. This worked on circuits that could not be powered down. I haven't seen the little button flashers for a few years I am not sure if they are still sold. Also it takes a large wattage lamp an LED probably would hard to detect because the current draw is so small.